# Custom graphs in Flex Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, graph

I am the designer for this graph which is part of a generated report - not the developer but before I present this to my client I wanted to know if this would be possible to be done in Flash builder. 
The coloured circles would be variable data based on the test results done prior to generate this report and the circle in the middle is the average score and their defined category.

I'm not a coder of any kind, I just need to know if its possible in this particular program for someone who knew what they were doing?

Any insights are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image: Example report graphic]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible: create a custom component in Flex and draw anything inside it.

Also you can easily embed .ai files in a Flex program by exporting them to .fxg

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the current Flex framework.

You could write a lot of custom code to achieve it though if you really had the time and money to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, though as @Clintm noted, it would require some custom coding.

The circles can easily be drawn using the drawing API, and a category could trigger some code to change the layering.